# Does Netezza have an ODBC DESCRIBE function?

Tags: sas, netezza, describe

I would like to DESCRIBE a table held on Netezza (so can see the variable formats, distribute on clause etc). I know this is possible (natively) using

`\d <tablename>`

However I am using SAS to connect (via ODBC).

Is this possible using SAS 9.1.3 code?

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully clear with your question, but I am assuming that you want to describe the table with nzsql command.
If Yes,
then try this 
nzsql -c "\d table_name"

Comment: have modified question.  We can only connect using SAS, so NZ commands are not possible (as far as i know).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to access the system views that hold the information about the tables.  You can't do this in one query, but you can do it with two.

```
SELECT  attname "Attribute", 
        datatype "Type", 
        CASE WHEN attnotnull='t' THEN 
            'Not Null' 
        ELSE 
            'Null' 
        END "Modifier",
        coldefault "Default"
FROM _v_relation_column col_t
    cross join _v_datatype dat_t
WHERE dat_t.objid = col_t.atttypid
    AND name='<table_name>'
ORDER BY attnum
;

SELECT attname  "Distributed on hash"
FROM _v_table_dist_map
    INNER JOIN tb_nm t ON tname = tablename
WHERE tablename ='<table_name>'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Netezza, but if you can connect to it with SAS/ACCESS then you should be able to use DBMS specific command with SQL Pass-Through.

documentation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245480.htm)