# Netezza find distribution key of a table programatically

Tags: netezza

Is it possible to programatically find what sort of distribution algorithm a Netezza table is using?

I can do it manually in Workbench by exporting table DDL but I would like to be able to do it programatically by running some sort of metadata SQL query.

I looked into most system tables but can't find this information anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399440/does-netezza-have-an-odbc-describe-function

Comment: Also related: http://www.topix.com/forum/com/netezza/T9PU3BV78RAUTTPNN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be a solution to this.

Running this query:

```
select * from _v_table_dist_map where database='database' and tablename='tablename';
```

If it returns no rows, it can be assumed a random distribution is being used (DISTRIBUTE ON RANDOM).

If it returns 1 or more rows, column based destribution is being used (DISTRIBUTE ON (col1, ..., coln)).

Comment: Same place you'd type the select above.

Comment: @ScottWilson Sorry I am still not sure what you mean. I can use Aginity client to interact with Netezza or I can use nzsql or nzload command on Linux.What do I so with \d ? Where do I enter that?

Comment: In nzsql at the prompt.

Comment: @ScottWilson Ah thanks. Here is what I have as a full example: `/usr/local/nz/bin/nzsql -h {host} -D {database} -u {user} -pw {passwords}  -c "\d {table_name}"`